# PHP 8 shell: can't input non-Ascii chars

Tags: php, linux, windows-subsystem-for-linux

After upgrading to PHP 8 in my WSL 2 I stuck with a strange problem: I can't input any non-ASCII character in shell, nor in interactive shell and PsySH.

I tried Russian, Serbian and some unicode symbols.

In simple words: if I try to input in shell "`Привет`" - russian letters just not get in terminal.

I have this behavior in Ubuntu 21.10 (bare metal) and 20.04 (WSL2). In Mac OS - everything fine.

Does anyone encounter this problem or have workaround for it?

Answer (score 0):

You may give a try on [Windows Terminal](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/p/windows-terminal/9n0dx20hk701?activetab=pivot:overviewtab). Here I use Traditional Chinese as an example:

[image]

It works perfectly with WSL 2 and I think Russian should work in your case too.

Comment: I use Windows Terminal :) But problem not with terminal, but with PHP Shell. Could you please run "php -a" and try to input Chinese text?

Comment: I don't have any problems

Answer (score 0):

It is a bug in PHP 8 version.
https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=81598